# Сравнение объекта и объекта в списке одного класса

Tags: c#, list, объекты

Нужно сравнить объект класса Planshet с объектами списка класса Planshet. Но при попытке в методе SearchPlanchet() с одинаковыми параметрами все равно выходит False. Заранее прошу прощения за быдлокод.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PlanshestsShop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Shop.BuyPlanshet();
            Shop.SearchPlanchet(Planshets._planshetList);
        }
    }
    public class Planshets
    {
        public static List<Planshet> _planshetList = new List<Planshet>(5)
        {
            new Planshet( Planshet.ModelsList.Samsung, Planshet.ColorCollection.Black, 2012, 1500),
            new Planshet( Planshet.ModelsList.Apple, Planshet.ColorCollection.Black, 2008, 2000),
            new Planshet( Planshet.ModelsList.Huawei, Planshet.ColorCollection.Blue, 2016, 4000),
            new Planshet( Planshet.ModelsList.Samsung, Planshet.ColorCollection.White, 2018, 5000),
            new Planshet( Planshet.ModelsList.Huawei, Planshet.ColorCollection.Black, 2020, 6000)
        };
    }
    public class Planshet
    {
        public enum ModelsList { Samsung, Huawei, Apple }
        public ModelsList Model { get; set; }
        public enum ColorCollection { White, Black, Blue }
        public ColorCollection Color { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Модель: {0} \nКолір: {1} \nРік: {2} \nЦіна: {3}", Model, Color, Year, Price);
        }
        public Planshet(ModelsList model, ColorCollection color, int year, int price)
        {
            Model = model;
            Color = color;
            Year = year;
            Price = price;
        }
    }
    public class Shop
    {
        static Planshet UserHotelka = new Planshet(Planshet.ModelsList.Samsung, Planshet.ColorCollection.Black, 0, 0);
        public static Planshet BuyPlanshet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Модель:");
            Console.WriteLine("0 - Samsung\t 1 - Huawei\t2 - Apple");
            int Choose = 0;
            Choose = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (Choose)
            {
                case 0: UserHotelka.Model = Planshet.ModelsList.Samsung; break;
                case 1: UserHotelka.Model = Planshet.ModelsList.Huawei; break;
                case 2: UserHotelka.Model = Planshet.ModelsList.Apple; break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Цвет:");
            Console.WriteLine("0 - Белый\t 1 - Черный\t2 - Синий");
            Choose = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (Choose)
            {
                case 0: UserHotelka.Color = Planshet.ColorCollection.White; break;
                case 1: UserHotelka.Color = Planshet.ColorCollection.Black; break;
                case 2: UserHotelka.Color = Planshet.ColorCollection.Blue; break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Год:");
            UserHotelka.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Цена:");
            UserHotelka.Price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return UserHotelka;
        }
        public static void SearchPlanchet(List<Planshet> _planshetList)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < _planshetList.Count; i++)
            {
                bool result = ValueType.Equals(_planshetList[i], UserHotelka);
                if (result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("aaa");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Пусто");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Equals поди не перегрузили

Comment: Вот это `ValueType.Equal` вам не подходит, так как оно значимые типы сравнивает, а у вас ссылочные

Answer (score 1):

Как отметил [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763), переопределите метод сравнения Equals для объекта Planshet:

```
public class Planshet
{
  //...
  
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (!typeof(Planshet).Equals(obj.GetType())) return false;
    Planshet value = (Planshet)obj;
    // здесь указать нужные критерии сравнения
    return
      value.Model == this.Model &&
      value.Color == this.Color;
  }
}
```

Затем, примените указанный метод для поиска. Например:

```
using System.Linq;
//...

public static void SearchPlanchet(List<Planshet> _planshetList)
{
  if (_planshetList.Any(x => x.Equals(UserHotelka)))
    Console.WriteLine("aaa");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Пусто");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Choose = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

лучше заменить на TryParse()

```
bool isSuccessfully = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out Choose);
```

метод поиска можно переписать так:

```
var _planshet = UserHotelka;// не обязательно
bool result = _planshetList.Exists(t => t.Color == _planshet.Color && t.Model == _planshet.Model);
// для упрощения я сравниваю только 2 параметра. но проверять надо все
if (result)
   Console.WriteLine("aaa");

else
   Console.WriteLine("Пусто");
```

Еще можно это сделать более красиво:

```
return string.Format("Модель: {0} \nКолір: {1} \nРік: {2} \nЦіна: {3}", Model, Color, Year, Price);
```

стало:

```
return $"Модель: {Model} \nКолір: {Color} \nРік: {Year} \nЦіна: {Price}";
```